# Getting folder name in NSIS at compile time

Tags: windows, batch-file, nsis

I would like to dynamically name my EXE files based on the folder in which they're being built. So, in other words, if my NSIS script is located in `C:\[blah]\MyProjectDir\Nullsoft\` and my project is located in `C:\[blah]\MyProjectDir\MyProject\` the output NSIS executable should be `MyProjectDir.exe`. I'm obviously obfuscating the names for simplicity, the structure of the folders has actual meaning to our team.

Basically the our (already written, ages ago) NSIS scripts look something like this:

```
!define APP_NAME "OurGUI"
!define PROJ_NAME "OurGUI"
!define PATH_TO_FILES ..\${PROJ_NAME}\bin\Debug
!define EXEC_NAME "OurGUI.exe"
OutFile "GUI_Setup.exe"
```

There's a whole bunch more that handle things like registry keys, installation, etc... this is the important part as it pertains to my question (because I don't want to modify the rest of the script).

I'd like to change it to something like this

```
!define M_NUMBER !system "for %I in (..) do echo %~nxI"

!define APP_NAME "${M_NUMBER}/ Demo GUI"
!define PROJ_NAME "OurGUI"
!define PATH_TO_FILES ..\${PROJ_NAME}\bin\Debug
!define EXEC_NAME "M_Number.exe"
OutFile "${M_NUMBER}_GUI_Setup.exe"
```

I know my syntax is totally off, but that's the idea.

Running the command `for %I in (..) do echo %~nxI` returns to me the name of the grandparent directory, which is exactly what I want. Now I need to figure out how to store it in some sort of variable so that it can be used in the `!define`'s. I need to somehow capture the output to the console (not the return value of `for`, which is always zero, within my NSIS script. Ideally I wouldn't have to use external plugins because that'll be a nightmare to manage across the team.

As a nice bonus, I'd also love to be able to manipulate the string (again, at compile time so it can be used in the `!define`'s.

The strings follow the format: `SWD1234-567`, but I would like to store it as `D1234567` in another variable for other renaming purposes. So, drop the "SW" and the "-" from the original string.

I'm open to other suggestions, but as a newbie to NSIS, this is what I've come up with.

Comment: Can you not set an environmental variable with a batch file before you run the NSIS script and then read that environmental variable like this: `$%envVarName%`

Comment: I'd rather not run a batch file before because I don't want to change the process of doing a release. But no reason I can't run it at the beginning of the script or something with !system or execwait

Comment: So are you saying you can do this: `!system "for %I in (..) do set envVarName=%~nxI"`

Comment: Oh idk. I doubt that's legal, doesn't compile for me. Just trying to convey the idea

Comment: You would probably have to use cmd.exe `!system 'cmd /c "for %I in (..) do set envVarName=%~nxI'"`

Comment: The env var is not going to propagate to the parent (makensis) process so you can't use `set` in `!system`. I'll come up with a solution tomorrow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `!system`+`!include` idiom to read the output of external commands:

```
!tempfile MYINCFILE
!system 'for %I in (..) do echo !define MYDIR "%~nxI" > "${MYINCFILE}"'
!include "${MYINCFILE}"
!delfile "${MYINCFILE}"
!echo "${MYDIR}"
```

The pre-processor has limited string handling but removing known sub-strings is possible:

```
!define MYDIR "SWD1234-567"
!searchreplace MYDIR2 "${MYDIR}" "SW" ""
!searchreplace MYDIR2 "${MYDIR2}" "-" ""
!echo "${MYDIR2}" ; D1234567
```